# Is there a way to recreate an ODI package using ODI Scenario?

Tags: oracle, package, scenarios, oracle-data-integrator, oracle-fusion-middleware

I mistakenly deleted an ODI package from my project which is very large in size. Is there a way to recreate the same package if I have a previously exported scenario for the same project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't any way to directly generate a deleted package from a scenario which you can see as a compiled version of the package.

Here are a couple of things to check to see if you can retrieve some information :

- When promoting from one environment to another, it's recommended to export the base object along with the scenario. That way you keep track of what was the code behind that scenario (black box). Bonus points if it's all versioned in a version control system (VCS).
- Starting with ODI 12.2.1, VCS can be directly integrated within ODI to version your code and create release archives. If that's the case you can restore a deleted object
  [image]
- Before 12.2.1 it was possible to use the internal versioning system of ODI that would store the objects in the Master Repository. You can restore it from the top menu.[image]
- If nothing of that is setup, you can still open the scenario export in any file editor and manually go through it to retrieve the logic. It's just an XML files that describes the different steps of your package. That would help you to rebuild it manually.

If you end up doing that last bullet point, now is probably a good time to improve your existing procedures and setup one of the three backup/versioning solutions mentioned above so it doesn't happen in the future.

Comment: Thanks Jerome. Unfortunately except this particular code that I accidentally deleted everything else had a backup (just too bad) . I ended up recreating the package from the scenario run steps. 
Cheers