# regenerate dropped interface from scenario or package in ODI 11G

Tags: interface, package, load, oracle-data-integrator, scenarios

I want to know if there is a way to recreate/recover an interface that was dropped by mistake, we can do it from the scenario or package?

If there is another solution please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't any way to directly generate a deleted object from a scenario. A scenarios, as you may know, it's a compiled version of the object.

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435052/is-there-a-way-to-recreate-an-odi-package-using-odi-scenario) can help you understand the options and the limits of ODI in your problem.